# show arrows when items are not empty

Tags: angular, npm, owl-carousel

Im using ngx-owl-carousel for the slider so far everything is working fine but the problem is when the list contain items it shows arrows but if there is no item in the list it still shows arrows for left and right navigation.

**HTML**

```
<owl-carousel [options]="carouselOptions" [items]="store" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row']" >
<div class="item" *ngFor="let store of store;let i= index">
<div class=" col-lg-12  select-store-box">
{{store.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: what is this `let store of store`? I hope it's a typo

Comment: store is actually  name of the object that contains the data.

Comment: you can't say `let a of a`, it should be `let item of array`